# Meteor browser policy

Tags: meteor, same-origin-policy

Recently I found out about browser policy package for Meteor from David Weldon (https://dweldon.silvrback.com/browser-policy), which I found from this checklist made by Sacha https://meteorjs.club/MeteorSecurityChecklist.pdf

I use the Google analytics for iron router package (https://github.com/reywood/meteor-iron-router-ga/) as well and I keep getting the following error after trying many different options (I expected BrowserPolicy.content.allowInlineScripts(); to allow this):

```
Refused to load the script 'data:application/javascript;base64,dmFyIHVyY2hpblRyYWNrZXI9ZnVuY3Rpb24oKXt9…JVcmw6ZnVuY3Rpb24obyl7cmV0dXJuIG87fSxfdHJhY2tFdmVudDpmdW5jdGlvbigpe319fX07' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' http://*.google-analytics.com https://*.google-analytics.com http://*.googleapis.com https://*.googleapis.com http://*.gstatic.com https://*.gstatic.com http://www.google-analytics.com https://www.google-analytics.com".
```

anyone can give me more insight in this?

Comment: Interestingly, iron-router-ga comes with its own browser policy. If you remove that package, does the error go away? I just want to verify that it's the cause.

Comment: @DavidWeldon it indeed does remove the error!

Comment: Okay that helps. So it looks like something is loading a data url and those are blocked by default I think. What happens if you add the package again, and then add `BrowserPolicy.content.allowDataUrlForAll()` to your policy?

Comment: @DavidWeldon ahh it's called a DataUrl (duh). That did the job, thanks so much again!

Comment: Great. I'll turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL in question is a Data URL, so one way to solve this is to add the following to your policy:

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowDataUrlForAll()
```

That's a pretty broad rule though. If you want to narrow it just to scripts you could do:

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowScriptDataUrl()
```